# apache2 rewrite rule css img js not loading

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

How to load css js file in localhost from remote host using rewrite rule ?

```
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} / [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/?id=2&te=1 [P]
```

I am using this rewrite rule to rewrite my localhost to example.com/?id=21&te=2 [P]. The site example.com is loading but file from css,js,img file is not loading

Comment: Open firebug and visit localhost in browser to see which css/js URLs are showing 404 to you.

Comment: Every css js img file is showing 404

Comment: Right I know but can you provide some those 404 URLs